# How do I use wait for exit when using C# to use a vbs file to run bat file?

Tags: c#, batch-file, vbscript

How do I use wait for exit when using C# to use a vbs file to run bat file?

### Currently, it does not wait until the vbs is done.  I have added the vbs code.

```
 private string SetBackUpFiles(string vbsFileName, CheckBox BackUpCheckBox)
    {
        Process proc = null;
        string BackUpCompleted;
        BackUpCompleted = "Back up function error";
        try
        {
            proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = vbsDir;
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = vbsFileName;
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            proc.Start();

            proc.WaitForExit();

            BackUpCompleted = "Backup Completed!";
            BackUpCheckBox.Checked = true;   
            BackUpCheckBox.Visible = true;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            BackUpCompleted = (ex.StackTrace.ToString());
        }
        return BackUpCompleted;
     }  
--------VBS script-----
Set oShell = CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell") 
Dim strArgs
strArgs = "cmd /c LayoutsBackup.bat"
oShell.Run strArgs, 0, false
```

Comment: what goes wrong?

Comment: The wait for exit does not work.

Comment: Show us the vbs code please.

Comment: Did you check for the exception that is caught?

Comment: The process gets completed, but the wait for exit does not wait... it is not waiting to complete these                                                     
            BackUpCompleted = "Backup Completed!";
            BackUpCheckBox.Checked = true;   
            BackUpCheckBox.Visible = true;

Comment: @BC you are executing an other command inside that VBA script that it runs an other `cmd`. So the vba script it just calls the cmd command and it exits without checking if the shell run has finished. Try to change your vba script like this `oShell.Run strArgs, 0, true`. Last parameter says the `Run` to wait until finish

Comment: @Christos Lytras   Thank you! That works.

Comment: @BC You're welcome. Will you mark my answer as accepted if I write this as an answer?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are executing an other command inside that VBS script that it runs an other `cmd`. So the VBS script it just calls the `cmd` command and it exits without checking if the shell run has finished. Try to change your VBScript like this:

```
oShell.Run strArgs, 0, true
```

[Run Documentation](https://ss64.com/vb/run.html)

> `.Run`
>
> Run an external Command.
>
> Syntax
>
> `objShell.Run (strCommand, [intWindowStyle], [bWaitOnReturn])`

Last parameter says the `Run` to wait until finish.